# Directx weird vertex shader issue

Tags: shader, directx

I'm in directX c++, when I give values to my vertex shader, if it's in a constant buffer or vertex buffer, the values completely disappear when they enter, what am I missing?

UPDATE THE FLOATS WERE NOT AN ISSUE BUT SOME OTHER VARIABLES ARE SET TO 0 FOR SOME REASON SO ITS THE SAME ISSUE

Comment: UPDATE THE FLOATS WERE NOT THE ISSUE BUT SOME OTHER VARIABLES ARE ALL SET TO 0

Answer (score 0):

THE PROBLEM WAS THAT I USED "INT" INSTEAD OF "UINT"